# Appending quotes to TinyMCE on each click instead of resetting

Tags: jquery, tinymce

I'm currently working on a quote feature for TinyMCE 4.

For each click, I'd like each selected quote to be appended to the TinyMCE editor instead of refreshing it.

Is this possible?

This is what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.quote').click(function () {
        var quote = $(this).data('content');
        var user = $(this).data('user');
        var content = '[quote='+ user +'] wrote: <br/> ' + quote + '[/quote]';
        tinyMCE.activeEditor.setContent(content);
        tinyMCE.activeEditor.getBody().firstChild.scrollIntoView();
    });
});
```

For example, if someone had already pressed the quote button, the quote would be in the editor. If someone presses it for another quote button, there would be two quotes in the editor, and the same for three and so on.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Use tinymce.activeEditor.execCommand('mceInsertContent', false, content); so your content can be added sequentially and doesn't get deleted.